# Сохранение файла в сетевой папке, выбранной в ShowBrowseFolderForm

Tags: delphi

Здравствуйте. Не могу избавиться от желания сохранять по диалогу, но нужно именно так.
Помогите, пожалуйста. Постоянно выдает ошибку о доступе к сети.
В благодарность не брошу изучать Delphi (ну нравится просто).

**Добавлено.**

Извините, конечно. Причем папка доступна всем. Все просто, но на Save проблемы, пишет нет доступа.

```
procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin ... Edit1.Text:=ShowBrowseFolderForm( 'Папка сохранения' ); ... // форма с выбором папки, все 
// отражается в Edit end;
procedure Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
begin Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(Edit1.Text+'namefale'); end;
```

Comment: а у вас есть права на запись в сетевую папку?) оО)

Comment: Папка открыта для всех

Comment: Дайте минимальный пример кода хоть, не всем интересно моделировать вашу ошибку

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте

```
Memo1.Lines.SaveToFile(Edit1.Text + PathDelim + 'namefale');
```

И вообще, попробуйте показать имя файла, чтобы убедиться, что все ок:

```
Showmessage(Edit1.Text + PathDelim + 'namefale');
```

Comment: Перепробовал. Не получается. Имя файла правильное (и .txt).
Не может создать. А в локальную папку - без проблем.
Что такое PathDelim? Не нашел. 
Жду с терпением.

Comment: PathDelim - это разделитель / или \ в зависимости от платформы.